# Thread and Handler handleMessage() performance

Tags: android

When I did profiling of the app, I have found that handleMessage() is looping and is taking time to show up my data in the ListView. Is there any other way to update the ListView in a more optimized way, so that I can see the view in full speed, which can be performance tuned?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that time spend too much in handleMessage ?